# Padding out a Timeline so all data will be displayed? (custom extent function?)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am abusing m.bostock's excellent [Brush & Zoom](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172) example to display data as discreet objects rather than as points along a path. Works fine except that, as the image below shows, since the last data point is used to define the `extent`, the resulting last data object can't be scrolled fully onto the screen.

This is probably a common issue with a simple fix but I've been poking around for an hour and haven't figured it out. Should I add a "dummy" event (date) at the end of my data set or is there a way to pad this out directly through code?

I'm thinking I need to tweak the `extent` here:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
```

but I'm not clear on how to do that

---

**Other relevant(?) code snippets**

```
  var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);

  var zoom = d3.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
            .translateExtent([[0, 0], [tlWidth, tlHeight]])
            .extent([[0, 0], [tlWidth, tlHeight]])
            .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

**Data Set**

```
date,eventText
January 1 2002, This is the first event
January 1 2004, Another event
January 1 2005, So many events!
January 1 2006, We have the BEST events
January 1 2007, Are we tired of winning yet?
January 1 2009, Are we done?
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `.range` of your `scaleTime`, so the chart takes up `labelWidth` less horizontal space. (Set `labelWidth` to whatever is appropriate).

It should suffice to change your current line—

```
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
```

—to—

```
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([ 0, width - labelWidth ])
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion! I tried it and while it "works" – it does so by making the x axis shorter (of course!) so that's not an acceptable solution – but it highlights my cognitive error (I'm new at d3) so that's good. The only way I can get what I want is by padding out the dates: adding "enough" time at the end of my data so that the last event box can fit in the viewport. I was hoping to generalize my code to handle any time range (days, months, etc) – so I will have to determine how much "time" the width of an event box represents in order to know how much padding to add.